# How to remove counter in TimeCircle?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-plugins, timer

I've looked around, but have not been able to find an answer to this question, and I do not even know if it is possible. In the TimeCircles.js plugin, is it possible to remove the counter value so that only the outer circle animation is displayed? The code snippet I have removes the "Seconds" text that is above the counter value, but I still want to get rid of the counter. If anyone could help me out, I would be very appreciative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it is open source you can hack it to do whatever you want. But if you want to use the legacy code, you can still workaround somehow.

I did not find any option to remove the counter, but you can try to check if setting it into a transparent font color with [rgba](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_colors_legal.asp) works for you.

> Advice: values can still be seen if you select the text with the cursor.

```
$(".example").TimeCircles({ time: {
  Days: { color: rgba(0,0,0,0) },
  Hours: { color: rgba(0,0,0,0) },
  Minutes: { color: rgba(0,0,0,0) },
  Seconds: { color: rgba(0,0,0,0) }
}});
```